# HTTP query create request error for oraclize

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, oracles

I have tried to deploy a sample contract having oraclizer query using truffle+ethereum bridge+solidity.  First ethereum bridge made up and got OAR address which is used in sample contract in constructor
OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0xCea1D31BdDDF90EdfDac30ca18665117Eefa011f);

Now whenever a function is called (update)in sample contract log is showing in the bridge terminal as shown in the image.. The query made to oraclizer through ethereum bridge is not successful. What could be the reason?[image]

Comment: See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset) for more info on ECONNRESET. It appears to usually be because of some mis-implementation on the API side. What API are you trying to connect with using Oraclize? Could you share your contract code?

Comment: the contract is taken from here ........https://github.com/bishesh16/simple-oraclize-solidity